# Using only Bash builtin commands and regex how can I remove the bold escape characters "^[[1m , ^[[0m" from a multiline variable?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

Using only Bash v2.02 builtin commands and regex how can I remove the  bold escape characters "^[[1m , ^[[0m" from a multiline variable?

Some example text is:

^[[1mSome Bold Text here^[[0m
^[[1mSome Bold Text there^[[0m

Comment: Usually you can have tools avoid printing ANSI escapes in the first place

Comment: Piping it into this: perl -ne 's/\e\[\d+m//g;print'  works, but I know this script is going to end up on system with Perl support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use extended pattern matching:

```
shopt -s extglob
x=$'abc\n\e[;1mdef\e[0m\nghi'
without="${x//$'\e'\[+([0-9;])m}"
```

This removes all possible colour changes from the variable.

Comment: The example you have give works. But not on the text I am trying to clean up for some reason. Surely something I am gumming up. Sry.

Comment: So just to spell it out, you need to enable `extglob` in order to use this. This is not regular expressions, but somewhat more powerful than the standard glob patterns.

Comment: Kudos for a _generic_ solution that covers _all_ formatting [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)  (style and color). I was tempted to simplify `$'\e'\[` to `$'\e['`, but that is actually _buggy_ in Bash 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

Without extglob:

```
x=$'\e[1mSome Bold Text here\e[0m \e[1mSome Bold Text there\e[0m'

e=$'\e'
x="${x//$e[0m/}"
x="${x//$e[1m/}"

echo "$x"
```

Comment: Well done; at least in Bash 3.2.57 you can simply embed ANSI C-quoted strings directly in the substitution; e.g., `x="${x//$'\e[0m/'}"`. In this specific case you could even get away with a _single_ substitution: `x="${x//$'\e['?'m'}"`